# Could not find gradle-7.0.3.jar

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle

When I want to run my application I get the following error:

```
> Could not find gradle-7.0.3.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.0.3/gradle-7.0.3.jar
```

so I tried to edit build.gradle and replace
`com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0` with `com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3`

but I still get this error.

Comment: Are you using Android Studio? Have you tried closing the project and opening it back again? It's likely that Android Studio just needs to re-index your project.

Comment: @Omatt yes i use android studio. and have done that and i still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

if you changed `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0` with `com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3` you also need to change in the same file this : `ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'`

find the kotlin version for your gradle version .

for example gradle:4.1.0 works with kotlin_version = 1.6.10

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation at https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle , you need to add the gradle plugin classpath to your project `build.gradle` at `projectName/android/build.gradle`. And you also need to add google maven `google()` for the repositories.

See the following example of project `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and you also need upgrading the gradle binary to version >= 7.0 like the documentation says

> You can specify the Gradle version in either the File > Project
> Structure > Project menu in Android Studio, or by editing the Gradle
> distribution reference in the gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
> file. The following example sets the Gradle version to 7.0.0 in the
> gradle-wrapper.properties file.

Go to `projectName/android/gradle/wrapper` and modified `gradle-wrapper.properties` so it becomes like the following (Remember to change the version to 7.0+):

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip
```